# How do I manually arrange the items in a folder in 14.04?

Tags: files, directory, 14.04

Icons can be arranged manually on the desktop, but I can't find any way to do it inside any other kind of folder. This is a big shame, as I used to (in 12.04) manually lay out and change the icons within some special folders. Also, I remember the zoom in level (ctrl +) used to get saved for particular folders, e.g. so icons would display uniformly bigger in a particular folder. Anyone have an idea how to get this functionality back, and why it went away in the first place? Thanks