# How to manually arrange files/folders in nautilus? (15.10)

Tags: unity, nautilus, 15.10

On the desktop, I can arbitrarily arrange files by dragging and dropping them wherever I wish. Is is possible to have the same functionality in nautilus? 
For example, I want to be able to open /home/music/ in nautilus and arrange each folder manually instead of having them automatically sorted by name, size, or filetype.

The same question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452811/how-do-i-manually-arrange-the-items-in-a-folder-in-14-04) but there are no answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A file manager with free icon placing option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843480/a-file-manager-with-free-icon-placing-option)